# How do I solve this fraction question?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

If $a = -1/5$, how do I calculate:

$$3 a + 2 a^2$$

I did $3\times(-1/5) + (-1/5) \times (-1/5) \times 2$, but can't figure out what the right way to solve this is.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/common-denominator.html

Comment: What goes wrong?  Can you compute $-\frac 15 \times -\frac 15 \times 2$ say?

Comment: How did you get that mark up for math symbols?

Comment: You can type -\frac{1}{5}, and enclose it with $ signs.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please tell us what you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: $a$ is the solution of $5a+1=0$. We can divide $2a^2+3a$ by $5a+1$ to get that $2a^2+3a=(5a+1)(2a/5+13/25)-13/25$. Putting $a=-1/5$ gives $2a^2+3a=-13/25$. :'D

Comment: @Bettybel If someone doesn't know how to multiply or add fractions, do you think they will understand how to divide polynomials and substitute into these types of equations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A helpful tip:
You can only add fractions with the same denominator (the numbers at the bottom). If the denominators are not equal, you have to multiply them by a constant number $k$  to add them.

Starting from $$\frac{3 \times -1}{5} + \frac{-1 \times -1 \times 2}{5\times5},$$
since $+a \times -b = -ab$, and $-a \times -b = ab$ for arbitrary numbers $a,b$, we have:

$$-\frac{3}{5} + \frac{2}{25}$$

Since $\frac{1}{5}$ is $5$ times that of $\frac{1}{25}$, $k=5$, and we have to multiply *both numerator and denominator* by $5$ to simplify:

$$-\frac{15}{25} + \frac{2}{25}$$

Now you can simplify the expression by cancelling $\frac{10}{25}$ and adding the $2$ fractions together:

$$-\frac{15}{25} + \frac{2}{25} = \frac{-15+2}{5}$$

I'll leave the last step for you to figure out.

Comment: Sorry everyone who was looking at a post with the wrong solution - I was half-awake writing this answer...

Answer (score 4):

That's the correct way.

\begin{align}
\left(3 \times \frac{-1}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{-1}{5} \times 2 \times \frac{-1}{5}\right) &= \frac{-3}{5}+\frac{2}{25} \\
&=\frac{-15}{25}+\frac{2}{25} \\
&= \frac{-13}{25}\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It might help you to add a denominator of $1$ to integers: $$\frac{3}{1} \times \frac{-1}{5} = \frac{-3}{5}.$$

So far so good, right? Next, $$\frac{2}{1} \times \left(\frac{-1}{5}\right)^2 = \frac{2}{1} \times \frac{1}{25} = \frac{2}{25}.$$

And then $$\frac{-3}{5} + \frac{2}{25} = \frac{-15}{25} + \frac{2}{25} = ?$$